# how to read file line by line in shell script and store each line in a variable

Tags: file, shell, unix

i am new in unix. i have to write a shell script which read a file line by line and store it in a separate variable. my text file contents multiple source path and one destination path.
something like this::

```
source_path=abc/xyz
source_path=pqr/abc
desination_path=abcd/mlk
```

number of source path can vary.
I dont have much hands on experience in Unix. Can anyone help me to achieve this one. It will be very helpfull.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You you want to store all soure_paths in one variable say separated by colon ?

Comment: no no, i want to store every path in a separate variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sourcePaths=( $(grep source_path myfile |cut -d= -f2) )
destPath=`grep destination_path myfile |cut -d= -f2`
```

`$sourcePaths` is an array of `source_path`s. You don't need to store each `source_path` in a separate variable.

You can loop over the array and do what you want with each `source_path`. For example:

```
for i in "${sourcePaths[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky but this should work:

```
old_IFS="$IFS"
IFS="="

while read left right ; do
  echo "Left side: $left"
  echo "Right side: $right"
done < $input_file

IFS="$old_IFS"
```

If you want to get rid of the `"` in `$right`, you might do something like `right_content=$(sed 's|"\(.*\)"|\1|' <<<$right)`. The `<<<$right` is almost like doing `echo $right`, and the sed command will remove leading and trailing `"` (if no quotation marks are present, the string will simply be passed as-is).

Comment: :thanx, but do you think that it will really work for multiple source path and store it in a different variable

Comment: :its not necessory that source_path will contents "".

Answer (score 0):

```
    #!/bin/sh
#path to config file
CONFIG_FILE=/tmp/conf.log
#check if file exist
if [[ -f $CONFIG_FILE ]]; then
#use source filename or .file name
    . $CONFIG_FILE
#test variable
echo "source is $source"
echo "dest is $dest"
fi
```