# Reading text file and store each line in distinct variables in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, cat

I have a text file with several lines and would like to write a bash script that reads the text file and store each line in different variable.

Here is how my file looks like.

```
cat file.txt

 line1
 line2
 line3
```

I would like to get the following:

```
variable1=line1
variable2=line2
variable3=line3
```

Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Use `readarray` (also known as `mapfile`) to read each line into an array. Then you can reference each line at the indexes `0 - n-1`.

Comment: what happens next will probably dictate the best solution.

Comment: True, but without knowing the number of lines before-hand, it would be impossible to read each line into an independently named variable without some type of `nameref` scheme.

Comment: Put each line into an array and then reference them by index is probably a better idea, please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30988704/10340970

Answer (score 2):

This question is unique in a sense it does *not* duplicate into any of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453/5291015), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7427262/5291015) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3720135/5291015). So answering the question henceforth.

You might need a loop that runs through the file and set variables on-the-fly as below.

```
n=1
while IFS= read -r "variable$n"; do
  n=$((n + 1))
done < file.txt
```

and print the variables to see the content retrieved

```
for ((i=1; i<n; i++)); do 
    var="variable$i"
    printf '%s\n' "${!var}"
done
```